# Saving files off of cell phone with no display

Tags: windows, windows-8, data-recovery, data-transfer

My Casio GZone flip phone fell in the lake. The computer recognized the device and installed the drivers. However, I do not have access to the flash memory to download the files.

Is this because the device is not in mass storage? The screen is gone so I can't read or view anything. would downloading Verizon software provide a way to download?

Comment: `Would downloading Verizon software provide a way to download?` You're kidding?? Why don't you try it?? -1

Answer (score 0):

Flip/feature phones are generally not designed to allow consumers to get contacts via the USB port.  (though for a while now they've supported moving all contacts to another phone via Bluetooth.)  It's designed for a service center to do that, or apply firmware upgrades, or possibly allow USB tethering if supported by the phone.

Your contacts are stored in the phone OS's storage and not on any SD card.

BitPim is an open source project that's attempting to reverse engineer some phones to allow transfer via computer- works on a lot of older Sprint and Verizon phones.  I don't think your phone is supported.

I worked at a Sprint service center for three years.  We had a machine called a "[Cellebrite](http://www.cellebrite.com/)" (it runs Windows CE, interestingly enough) that can read (either transfer to another phone or save to a file that can be printed) and write the contacts of any phone in existence.  This is needed in cell phone shops so that sales people can move people's contacts during phone upgrades, so any cell phone store ought to have one.

So I would take it to a Verizon store and ask for them to try to print your contacts off of their Cellebrite.

Of course, given that your phone got liquid damaged, it may not work, but from what you are saying, it's not totally dead, so it's worth a shot.  You could also find another working GZ'one off of Ebay or similar and try to switch the displays (typically the displays are connected by a flat ribbon cable that pops up) if you are comfortable taking it apart.